# Ruby on Rails: Is there any way to pull items from the database and have them returned in a specified order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an array of item ID's, `item_ids`.

I'm passing this array into an ActiveRecord query to retrieve the corresponding items from the database: `Item.where(:id => item_ids)`

Is there any way to get the items returned in the same order as passed in via the `item_ids` array?

If it makes a difference,  I'm on Ruby on Rails 3.0.12 with PostgreSQL as my database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the database to do the sorting and avoid multiple [`index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index) calls, you just have to remember that an SQL ORDER BY orders by an *expression*, not a *column*:

```
whens = item_ids.collect.with_index { |id, i| "when #{id} then #{i}" }.join(' ')
items = Item.where(:id => item_ids).order("case id #{whens} end")
```